# Executing multiple commands in a scriptblock and returning multiple responses

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I'd like to connect to a remote host, run 2 commands and return the seperate responses. However I'd like to do this as part of one scriptblock. I've done this before with one command but no joy with two. For example having

```
gc "C:\test.txt"
```

and

```
get-webservice | ? {$_.Name -eq "foo"}
```

combined into a scriptblock and passing that scriptblock to **Invoke-Command** and extracting the individual responses from that call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to load your results into a hash table, the return that.

```
$Scriptblock = 
{
  $response = @{}
  $response.dir = gc "C:\test.txt"
  $response.service = get-webservice | ? {$_.Name -eq "w32time"}
  $response
}

$result = &$Scriptblock
```

This eliminates any ambiguity in the results of any of the commands returns a null.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand your problem, have you tried like this:

```
$Workload = {
    $TestText = Get-Content "C:\test.txt"
    $WebServices = Get-WebService | ? {$_.Name -eq "foo"}

    $TestText,$WebServices
}

$FirstJob,$SecondJob = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock $Workload
```

Comment: I gave it a plus one point, but wanted to add this  observation: the output from $WebServices shows up for $FirstJob, and versa-visa, I would have expected the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scriptBlockContent ($myFile)
{
    $TestText = Get-Content $myFile
    $WebServices = Get-WebService | ? {$_.Name -eq "foo"}

    $TestText,$WebServices
}

$FirstJob,$SecondJob = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock ${function:scriptBlockContent} -ArgumentList $myFile
```